# Detect if input type 'number' was increased or decreased from previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a good way to do this? Can you send the original value as well as the new value to jquery/javascript function? Keeping the old value in some global variable just feels a little messy.

EDIT: Context code

```
<input type='number' onchange='foo(...)'>

...

<script type=text/javascript>
function foo(...){
    if(old > new){
        alert('decreased');
    }else{
        alert('increased');
    }
}
</text>
```

Comment: Can we see some context code?

Comment: You're going to have to keep the old value around, and in scope. If you're working in the global space, then you'll have to store it globally. You may consider wrapping the code so it doesn't pollute the global space though . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So don't keep it in a global variable:

```
<input type="number" value="5" />

$('input[type="number"]').change(function () {
    if (this.getAttribute('value') === this.value) {
        // setting the original 'lastvalue' data property
        $(this).data('lastvalue', this.value);
    } else {
        // take whatever action you require here:
        console.log(this.value < $(this).data('lastvalue') ? 'decrement' : 'increment');
        // update the lastvalue data property here:
        $(this).data('lastvalue', this.value);
    }
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vpWLM/).

You could also, in place of `this.getAttribute('value') === this.value` use instead `this.defaultValue === this.value` (as in this [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vpWLM/1/)), `this.defaultValue` being the original value of the element on DOM-ready.

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `this.getAttribute('lastvalue')`?

Comment: No, because **a)** there is no 'lastvalue' attribute\*, and **b)** the `if` is simply to establish the `lastvalue` property of the data object on the first run (triggered by the `change()` in the last line of the chain). (\* the `data()` method will some properties equal to the `data-*` prefixed attributes, if they exist, but won't update those attributes, and will keep them in an object for later access.)

Comment: Oh, I see now what you did there... :)  However, this wouldn't catch a decrement from 6 to 5 (after a previous increment from 5 to 6)?